# Make my current Public IP address unchangeable.

Tags: windows, windows-7, ip, router

I have manged to sign up in a service. and this service only authorize with your public address, I gave the my public IP address, and I didn't find out that until It was too late, because some times my [Linksys Wag54gs router](http://yvan.seth.id.au/Entries/2006/09/linksys-wag54gs-is-crap/) have some issues and  every 24-36 hours it reboots itself. and with that, It gives me a new public IP address, I want now to assign this IP I have to my computer as my Unchangeable IP address so, It'd give me this one every time I connect to a new network and/or my router reboots.

I found a lot of answers to my question by googling, but the problem is that they required giving a new IP address, and then It'd ( the one that they just give me ) be unchangeable, But It's bad for me since I can't 'update' my new IP.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your ISP controls that, not your router. Email them and ask for a *static ip address* (they may charge)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer: You can't. That's a decision of your ISP to change your IP once in a while (in some countries, they are required to do so by law for privacy reasons).

There are services which update your DNS registration whenever your IP changes, such as dyndns.com or others. They're usually not entirely free, though.

You could also talk to your ISP to give you a static IP, although that costs you some $$$, too, if they offer this service at all.

Comment: They usually give you a static IP address based on my MAC address ? that'd make them think I have a website and try registering for a domain. and would cost a lot for me.

Comment: It'd be great if there's another way around that.

Comment: @JustCurious: If you're not trying to create a website, why would you need a static IP at all?

Comment: Well, I explained why in the question section but tl;dr: Because I signed up in a service that requires you're IP address to log in, so once my IP change change, I'd lose it. and I can't just update it.

Comment: Hmm... That's a weird service then. Maybe you contact them and ask whether they've never heard of dynamic IPs? Sounds really odd to me.

Comment: Yeah, I know. I contacted them about the problem and they replied with "I'm sorry we don't support that at the time, and unfortunately if you're IP changed. you'll be no longer able to access our service and had to re-signup again" and signup isn't free.

Comment: and they don't accept dynamic IPs once you change it you lose it. you can't just update you're new IP

Comment: That's just stupid. That would be a reason to ask my money back because of an inherent error in their offering. You wouldn't accept a car that can be started only once, would you?

Comment: Now, after you understand ( hope you did ;) ) I want to know how to fix my problem ?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know how to solve that problem. There's no way you can keep your IP static without an explicit configuration by your ISP. Further still, there's no way you can get a _specific_ IP assigned, such as the one you had when you registered, as that one already belongs to someone else meanwhile. The only chance you'd have around that is maybe use the computer at your office. If you're working in a large company, they may be having static global IPs.

Comment: my IP changed already due to [this crap](http://yvan.seth.id.au/Entries/2006/09/linksys-wag54gs-is-crap/) now, I'm having hard time about it.